# [ANSI-C]Use struct like a class

Tags: c, oop, struct

i'm developing a "first" C software for an embedded device.

I would like write code in a oo-style, so i started to use structs.

```
typedef struct sDrawable {
    Dimension size;
    Point location;
    struct sDrawable* parent;
    bool repaint;
    bool focused;
    paintFunc paint;
} Drawable;

typedef struct sPanel {
    Drawable drw;
    struct sDrawable* child;
    uint16_t bgColor;
} Panel;
```

I can't and i don't want use malloc, so i search the better way to instantiate my structs.
Is this acceptable?

```
Panel aPanel={0};

void Gui_newPanel(Panel* obj, uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t w, uint16_t h, uint16_t bgColor) {
    // Drw is a macro to cast to (Drawable*)
    Drw(obj)->repaint = true;
    Drw(obj)->parent= NULL;
    Drw(obj)->paint = (paintFunc) &paintPanel;
    Drw(obj)->location=(Point){x, y};
    Drw(obj)->size=(Dimensione){w, h};
    obj->child = NULL;
    obj->bgColor = bgColor;
}

void Gui_init(){
    Gui_newPanel(&aPanel, 0, 0, 100, 100, RED);
}
```

**UPDATE**

In the first one, i have to initialize struct like `Panel aPanel={0};` to pass its pointer to Gui_newPanel function, or i can only write `Panel aPanel;` ?
I have tested and both works, but maybe i'm only unlucky...

Or is this a better way?

```
Panel aPanel;

Panel Gui_newPanel(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t w, uint16_t h, uint16_t bgColor) {
    // Drw is a macro to cast to (Drawable*)
    Panel obj;
    Drw(&obj)->repaint = true;
    Drw(&obj)->parent= NULL;
    Drw(&obj)->paint = (paintFunc) &paintPanel;
    Drw(&obj)->location = (Point){x, y};
    Drw(&obj)->size = (Dimension){w, h};
    obj.child = NULL;
    obj.bgColor = bgColor;
    return obj;
}

void Gui_init(){
    aPanel=Gui_newPanel(0, 0, 100, 100, RED);
}
```

Which of these methods is preferable?

I am particularly interested in performance and memory usages.

Thanks

Comment: Surely *not* the second one, because `obj` is only "valid" inside the `Gui_newPanel`.

Comment: @blow: turn on your compiler warnings.  It may "work" as long as the stack memory at that address hasn't been over-written, which it will be sooner or later.  In any case, don't it!

Comment: You're better off with the first option. The 2nd option entails a lot of copying ...

Comment: @blow: I stand corrected about the copy issue -- sorry.  It will work.

Comment: @goldilocks:no probs, thank you anyway!

Comment: I have update my first question.

Comment: @blow that should really be a separate question.  If you don't initialize `aPanel` with `={0}` then anything that you forget to initialize in `Gui_newPanel` will contain garbage (unless `aPanel` is declared at file scope, outside a function).

Comment: @ecatmur: so if i declare it outside any function, i can omit {0}, correct?

Comment: Yes, a struct declared outside a function will have all elements initialised to 0 automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning `struct`s by value can incur overhead of copying the struct members, although the compiler will often be smart enough to optimise this out.  If you're concerned as to the overhead, you should profile the relative performance of the two approaches.

Also, check whether the target compiler for the device is actually able to support returning structs - some very old compilers don't support returning or assignment of structs.

If you have a reasonably modern compiler, you may be able to return a `struct` literal directly, which will be efficient:

```
return (Panel) {
    .drw = {
        .size = {w, h},
        .location = {x, y},
        // ...
    },
    .child = NULL,
    .bgColor = bgColor
};
```

Comment: Thank you, i'm using microchip C30 compiler, i'm not sure if it optimize this, so i will use the frst way. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah it works!
Can you explain me why this is more efficient?

Comment: @blow it's more efficient because (typically) the struct will be constructed directly into the object that you assign the return value to.  It actually compiles to pretty much the same code as your first method, passing a "hidden pointer parameter" to the function.

Comment: I think a smart compiler could apply the same optimization when compiling the second variant... but thank you for letting me know about this syntax, I never saw it before :-)